# Plotting CLLocation/CLLocationCoordinate2D on a MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am obtaining the users location via Parse and the object is returned as a PFGeoPoint. I have converted it to a CLLocation / CLLocationCoordinate2D by doing so:

```
CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.geoPoint.latitude longitude:self.geoPoint.longitude];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [loc coordinate];
```

Question is to add an annotation on a mapView it appears I need a MKPointAnnotation. How would I go about converting what I have to be able to add it to my mapView?

Comment: Creating the CLLocation is unnecessary.  A CLLocationCoordinate2D can be created directly using CLLocationCoordinate2DMake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a MKPointAnnotation for a specific location this way:

```
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
```

This annotation can then be added to the map view.

```
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```